# How to compile multiple scripts with py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I have been recently working on a text game (executes in the console or CMD). I already tested it and it works perfectly. But now I want to make it a SINGLE EXE. I have already done that with other scripts. The proble is that this game is actually made of 3 scripts:main.py ,maps.py, UInterface.py. This are all imported in the main file like this

```
   import maps;
   import UInterface as UI;
```

What can I do to have everything into a single exe and make it work?
Repeat, my code already worked, just need compiling

Comment: You should be use py2exe the same way you did with single file scripts. Normally it's able to figure out what modules your script imports and include them along with everything else.

Comment: Do you mean I should only compile main.py and the rest will compile automatically?

Comment: Py2exe isn't a actually a compiler, it just bundles your Python code with the Python interpreter. But, yes, if you tell it make `main.py` into an executable it should find `maps.py` and `UInterface.py` and include them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download and install - py2exe (link here http://www.py2exe.org/)
2. Create a setup.py like this (in the source dir):

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

   setup(console = ['main.py'])
   ```
3. And then run as:

   ```
   python setup.py py2exe
   ```
4. exe will get creted here **.\dist\main.exe**

Answer (score 0):

SITUATION:

- You have a "main script" that calls "other scripts" (in the same
  folder or in packages) created by yourself.

---

SHORT ANSWER:

- First: You need to compile with py2exe ONLY the main script.
- Py2exe can't find your "other scripts". To fix it, copy that code at
  the beginning of setup.py (changing main_script_dir of course)

  > ```
  > import sys
  > main_script_dir = "folder1\\folder2\\main.py"
  > main_folder = main_script_dir.rsplit("\\",1)[0]
  > sys.path.append(main_folder)
  > ```

It removes the name of the script, and adds the folder to the PYTHONPATH.

---

LARGE ANSWER:
(The explanation about how to arrive to the conclusion)

**How can you test that py2exe can't find your "other scripts"?**

- Run py2exe with a simple .bat file that contents cd commands to find
  setup.py, the run command, and a wait time command that allows you to
  read the output information in the console after.

> ```
> cd..
> cd..
> cd..
> cd..
> cd..
> cd Folder1
> cd Folder2
>
> "C:\Python27\python.exe" setup.py py2exe
>
> >nul ping -n 30 localhost
> ```

- You can find now a warning like "The following modules appear to be
  missing" (use right click > find if you want)

**Why did it happen?**

- Py2exe looks for "other scripts" similar to import function (in the
  modules already imported, the main script folder, pythonpath's
  directories, etc). However, py2exe omits the main script folder
  (maybe it's a bug). That's why you won't have problems if you copy
  your "other scripts" in site-packages folder, for example.

**How can you solve this?**

You have to add the main script directory to the pythonpath:

- (not recommended) ‎If you modify it with control panel the changes
  will remain after the program closes.

(like this: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-thepythonpath-in-windows-7))

- (recommended) If you modify it with code (following the steps
  detailed above in the short answer), the changes will remain only
  until the program closes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I come across this post trying to create a set of executables from some independent scripts.  Eventually, I solved this by putting all the script names assigned to console.  From the documentation, console is the keyword for a list of scripts to convert into console exes.

Example:

```py
setup(console=[
    'script1.py',
    'script2.py',
    'script3.py'
    ]
)
```

Hope this helps somebody trying to do the same thing.